# como arreglar sopa de letras

Tags: python

No puedo solucionar este error que me marca al realizar mi matriz/sopa de letras

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
> "c:\Users\Usuario\Desktop\menu.py", line 15, in 
> matriz_alfabeto[i][j] = alfabeto[random.randint(0,25)] TypeError: 'NoneType' object does not support item assignment PS
> C:\Users\Usuario\Desktop\p>

y este es el codigo:

```
import random 

alfabeto = ["a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i","j","k","l","m","n","o","p","q","r","s","t","u","v","w","x","y","z"]

matriz_alfabeto = [None] * 10

palabra_1 = ["p","r","o","g","r","a","m","a"]
palabra_2 = ["v","a","r","i","a","b","l","e"]

for i in range(0,10):
    matriz_alfabeto = [None] * 10

for i in range(0,10):
    for j in range(0,10): 
        matriz_alfabeto[i][j] = alfabeto[random.randint(0,25)]

for i in range(8):
    matriz_alfabeto[i][0] = palabra_1[i]
    matriz_alfabeto[9][i] = palabra_2[i]

print(matriz_alfabeto)
```

Comment: La lista que creas: `matriz_alfabeto` es `[None, None, None, ...]`. Sin embargo, la estás tratando como una lista de listas.

Comment: Lo que querías hacer era `[[None, None,...], [None, None,...], ...]`?

Comment: no yo no queria hacer [[None, None,...], [None, None,...], ...] puede ser que me este salteando algo pero no me doy cuenta

Comment: Como deseas que sea la lista que asignas a matriz_alfabeto entonces?

Comment: Voy a poner una respuesta, pero no estoy seguro si es lo que buscas.

Comment: si era eso lo que buscaba muchas gracias

Comment: De nada Angel c:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tu error se encuentra en este sector:

```
for i in range(0,10):
    matriz_alfabeto = [None] * 10
```

Aqui lo que haces es establecer el valor de `matriz_alfabeto` a `[None]*10` cada vez que el for se ejecuta.
Leyendo tu comentario, supongo que lo que buscabas hacer era asignar `[None]*10` a cada item de `matriz_alfabeto`. Para eso tendrías que hacer así:

```
for i in range(0,10):
    matriz_alfabeto[i] = [None] * 10
```